# Ubuntu 15.04 - Won't allow 2560x1440 on Intel anymore

Tags: xorg, resolution, intel-graphics, 15.04

I was previously running Ubuntu 13.04 on a machine with Intel HD4600 integrated graphics at 2560x1440p on a Dell Ultrasharp u2713hm via DVI Dual-Link without issue.

Since upgrading to 15.04 however, it refuses to recognize resolutions above 1920x1200. I've installed the latest Intel drivers and they appear to be loading correctly.

I can manually set the resolution to 2560x1440p using xrandr - and it works correctly for a short period of time, however for some reason some applications will reset it back to 1920x1200

For example - if I run "Dropbox" it'll revert back to 1920 and refuse to switch using xrandr until I've killed the offending application.

The Ubuntu screen settings dialog also resets the resolution, and then only lets me choose a lower 1920x1200 resolution.

Is there any way to force `xorg` to explicitly recognize 2560x1440 as a valid resolution, therefore presumably not resetting to a lower point whenever any application hits whatever API is forcing it to revert?

Comment: For anyone else experiencing this issue - I resolve by switching to a DisplayPort cable.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's helpful to cut out adapters when testing. I experienced the exact same issue as James; my problem was a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter capping the graphics to 1920x1200.

A digital media professional explained to me there are capability negotiations going on behind the scenes and the cheaper adapters take a lot of shortcuts, hence the low price.

HDMI to HDMI had worked fine with this monitor on a previous system.
**Cutting out a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter and using a DisplayPort cable helped** to get my new system running flawlessly at 2560x1440.